# Change content of Model Browser in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there an easy way to change the content of Model Browser in the Forge Viewer? I would like to rename som nodes, add and remove node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Model Browser sources its data from the object tree (`model.getInstanceTree()`) which is immutable and can only be extended by re-creating your own data structure.

Here’s a couple of good starting points:

- Data Structure: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/supporting-multiple-models-new-modelstructurepanel
- Behavior: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/customizing-modelstructurepanel-behavior-forge-viewer
- Code Sample: https://github.com/yiskang/forge-au-sample/tree/master/model-structure