# How do model browsers categorize by floor or default and display together

Tags: autodesk-forge, viewer

this is the default classification

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDma2.png)

This is floor derivation. The first level classification is floor, and then the default classification is inside.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqPnb.png)

How can these two categories be displayed together in the model browser to switch between two tabs? Together, it can facilitate users to better switch between explicit and implicit.

Secondly, how to make a list of model browsers with relevant data?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Change content of Model Browser in Forge Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53792642/change-content-of-model-browser-in-forge-viewer/53825800#53825800).

There was indeed a hack to restructure/customise the object tree for Model Browser prior to Viewer V3, but that feature had been removed in later versions, which leaves us with pretty much rebuilding our own Model Browser as the only viable approach to accomplishing, within Viewer, the classification you’re after. See the other question above for details.